# how can I determine whether an email header is base64 encoded

Tags: python-2.7, email

Using the email.header package, I can do

```
the_text,the_charset = decode_header(inputText)
```

to get the character set of the email header, where the inputText was retrieved by a command like

```
inputText = msg.get('From')
```

to use the From: header as an example.

in order to extract the header encoding for that header, do I have to do something like this?:

```
the_header_encoding = email.charset.Charset(the_charset).header_encoding
```

That is, do I have to create an instance of the Charset class based on the name of the charset (and would that even work?), or is there a way to extract the header encoding more directly from the header itself?

Comment: `decode_header` decodes the header from base64 or quoted printable encoding as needed; the `the_charset` component is the *codec* declared in the header.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That was how I understood decode_header, but for other reasons I still need to know if the header had been base64 encoded or not.  Can I get that info by the method I suggested?  Or is there an easier way?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are looking for. Do you want to know if the header uses the [Encoded-Word syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word), and if so, if base64 or quoted-printable was used?

Comment: Note that a header can include *multiple* encoded-word sections, and that each could potentially use a *different* encoding! Did you want the whole list in that case?

Comment: Looking at the Wiki @MartijnPieters quoted above, it looks like maybe I should just parse the Q or B out of the original header manually, unless Python provides ready access to this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73432/discussion-between-purplevermont-and-martijn-pieters).

Comment: looks like my original decode_header use was incorrect, since decode_header will return a list of pairs (in the case of multiple sections)

Answer (score 1):

[Encoded-Message](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word) header can consist of 1 or more lines, and each line can use a different encoding, or no encoding at all.

You'll have to parse the type of encoding out yourself, one per line. Using a regular expression:

```
import re

quopri_entry = re.compile(r'=\?[\w-]+\?(?P<encoding>[QB])\?[^?]+?\?=', flags=re.I)
encodings = {'Q': 'quoted-printable', 'B': 'base64'}

def encoded_message_codecs(header):
    used = []
    for line in header.splitlines():
        entry = quopri_entry.search(line)
        if not entry:
            used.append(None)
            continue
        used.append(encodings.get(entry.group('encoding').upper(), 'unknown'))
    return used
```

This returns a list of strings drawn from `quoted-printable`, `base64`, `unknown` or `None` if no Encoded-Message was used for that line.